# jQuery Accordion plugin - Videos is not getting loaded in ipad

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ipad

We have used the jquery accordion plugin in our home page. When the user clicks on each slide of the accordion slider, we have dynamically generated the 'Videos' and 'Source' tags. After that we have used the load() and play() function to play the videos. It is working fine for us in desktop browser but it could not be played in ipad device. Can any one please assist my request and do the needful.

### Code:

### Generating Video tags when expanding the accordion image:

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ) { //alert("append1");
            var videoStartTag   = "<video id='"+e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_mp4src").attr('id')+"_vid' class='accordion-video' controls width='100%' height='100%' loop style='background: black;'>";
            var videoEndTag   =  "</video>";  
            var videoAccordion  = '';
            //alert("====>"+e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_mp4src").attr('id'));
            //alert("=====>"+e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_mp4src").val());
            if(jQuery.trim(e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_mp4src").val()) != ""){
              videoAccordion  +=  "<source src='"+jQuery.trim(e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_mp4src").val())+"' type='video/mp4'>";
            }
            if(jQuery.trim(e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_oggsrc").val()) != ""){
              videoAccordion  +=  '<source src="'+jQuery.trim(e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_oggsrc").val())+'" type="video/ogg">';
            }
            if(jQuery.trim(e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_websrc").val()) != ""){
              videoAccordion  +=  '<source src="'+jQuery.trim(e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_websrc").val())+'" type="video/webm">';
            }
            //alert("==1=>"+videoAccordion);
            e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion-video").remove();
            if(videoAccordion != "")
              e.accordionSegment.find(".accordion_mp4src").before(videoStartTag + videoAccordion + videoEndTag);
    }
```

### Play Videos:

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) ) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                      //alert("===>"+jQuery(".category-accordion").find(".accordion_mp4src").attr("id"));
                      var temp = jQuery(".category-accordion").find(".accordion_mp4src").attr("id");
                      document.getElementById(temp+"_vid").load();
                      document.getElementById(temp+"_vid").play();
                });
            }
```

Thanks,
Arularasan D.

Answer (score 0):

Video elements don't play automatically on iOS, you can use some technique called Canvas to render your video in another way: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/.

Or you can use something like an image sequence: http://www.sequencejs.com/

Otherwise it is not possible to play a video on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have checked this demo url:http://html5doctor.com/demos/video-canvas-magic/demo1.html using canvas tag in my ipad. But i din't get the video play action.

Comment: Hm too bad, must have something to do with the video element not playing at all. I would go for another solution or try the image sequence, pretty sure that works!